# How do I correct my CSS to make a strange grey box inside my button disappear?

Tags: css, button

I needed to make a new button for our website. I took CSS that works somewhere else on the website, copied it, and made minor adjustments. Instead of producing a button more or less like this: [Good button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EJ2l3.png) I instead get a weird gray box inside of the button surrounding the text of the button like this: [Bad button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dezX6.png). (The dark grey is just the background of the website.) I'm a complete scrub when it comes to CSS, but the code looks basically identical from one button to the next. If it matters, the website editor in question is responsivesiteeditor.

We no longer have a full time person to handle these kinds of problems, so a full explanation of what's going on (or links to your favorite explainers on what went wrong) are really appreciated.

Here's my code for the bad button.

```
    float:none !important;
    top:0 !important;
    left:0 !important;
    text-align:Center !important;
    width:calc(100% - 311px) !important;
    position:Relative !important;
    height:60px !important;
    background-color:#ad665a !important;
    padding-top:0px !important;
    padding-left:60px !important;
    padding-bottom:0px !important;
    margin-right:0px !important;
    margin-left:540px !important;
    max-width:159px !important;
    margin-top:10px !important;
    margin-bottom:10px !important;
    padding-right:0px !important;
    min-width:25px !important;
    text-align:start !important;
    display:block !important;
    background-color:#ad665a !important;
    border:none !important;
    color:white !important;
    padding:15px 32px !important;
    text-align:center !important;
    display:inline-block !important;
    font-size:16px !important;
    border-radius:8px !important;
```

Here's my code for the good button

```
 float:none !important;
    top:0 !important;
    left:0 !important;
    width:calc(100% - 311px) !important;
    position:relative !important;
    height:91px !important;
    padding-top:0px !important;
    padding-left:0px !important;
    padding-bottom:0px !important;
    margin-right:311.5px !important;
    margin-left:311.5px !important;
    max-width:159px !important;
    margin-top:10px !important;
    margin-bottom:10px !important;
    padding-right:0px !important;
    min-width:25px !important;
    text-align:start !important;
    display:block !important;
```

I've adjusted some things and fought with it to make it right for the new context, but even if I go back to the original coding, I get the same grey box.

Comment: Can you share the HTML snippet of the button?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I dont know the structure of the website but as far as I can see you are using way too much properties for a simple button.

If you want the exact same button as the red one, you can copy the properties and change the background-color of the button to green.

e.g :

```css
      .bad {
            float: none !important;
            top: 0 !important;
            left: 0 !important;
            text-align: Center !important;
            width: calc(100% - 311px) !important;
            position: Relative !important;
            height: 60px !important;
            background-color: #ad665a !important;
            min-width: 25px !important;
            text-align: start !important;
            display: block !important;
            background-color: #ad665a !important;
            border: none !important;
            color: white !important;
            padding: 15px 32px !important;
            text-align: center !important;
            display: inline-block !important;
            font-size: 16px !important;
            border-radius: 8px !important;
        }

        .good {
            float: none !important;
            top: 0 !important;
            left: 0 !important;
            text-align: Center !important;
            width: calc(100% - 311px) !important;
            position: Relative !important;
            height: 60px !important;
            background-color: green !important;
            min-width: 25px !important;
            text-align: start !important;
            display: block !important;
            border: none !important;
            color: white !important;
            padding: 15px 32px !important;
            text-align: center !important;
            display: inline-block !important;
            font-size: 16px !important;
            border-radius: 8px !important;
        }
```

```html
    <button class="bad">
        bad button
    </button>


    <button class="good">
       good button
    </button>
```

If you want to know more about buttons, how to use and style them I suggest you look into this topic on W3Schools:

[W3Schools CSS Buttons](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_buttons.asp)

Comment: To Clarify, I inherited the code from a previous runner of the site. The good button's code when copied produced the same grey box.

Comment: Why not put everything that is the same in both classes into a .button class? You still copy a lot of lines even though the only thing that differs is the background color.

Comment: I know, but OP has limited knowledge on the subject so I tried to simplify it, even though it's not the best practice to do so.